# while x for at javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, loops

I'm testing the loops for and while for javascript and got this situation:

```
function loopWithWhileOneBillion() {
    var max = 1000000000; //1kkk
    var date1 = new Date();
    var inc = 0;
    while (max--) {
        inc++;
    }
    var date2 = new Date();
    return date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
}

function loopWithForOneBillion() {
    var max = 1000000000; //1kkk
    var date1 = new Date();
    var inc = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        inc++;
    }
    var date2 = new Date();
    return date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
}
/* *************************************** */

/* loop with 10kkk interactions */
function loopWithWhileTenBillion() {
    var max = 10000000000; //10kkk
    var date1 = new Date();
    var inc = 0;
    while (max--) {
        inc++;
    }
    var date2 = new Date();
    return date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
}

function loopWithForTenBillion() {
    var max = 10000000000; //10kkk
    var date1 = new Date();
    var inc = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        inc++;
    }
    var date2 = new Date();
    return date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
}
```

My code is testing a for and a while loop for one billion and ten billion interactions. I guess that the while is most optimized as possible, then the while would be better than for in all situation but it does not occourring like I imagined. Is there a better loop to a specific condition? Is there a browser optimization to these loops? In front-end case, I imagine that should not have all interactions like I did in this example, but in an application with node could have. Is there a optimization for loops in v8?

http://jsfiddle.net/alexfqc/vfmgc73n/

Comment: http://jsperf.com/loops

Comment: The performance difference between the different loops won't be noticeable in most situations.  Anyway modern compilers and engine are written in a way that they will optimized code according to experience with real code, so most of the time such _specialized_ test result in meaningless results as they don't reflect any real usage scenario.

Comment: Your `for` and `while` loops are not equivalent: Your `for` loop increments two variables and compares two variables; your `while` loop decrements one variable and increments another, and compares a variable to a *constant*. So starting point: Make the loops equivalent. Then you'll find performance of them is equivalent (barring measurement error).

Comment: My while is different to be "more efficient" than the for. I did i reverse while thinking in performance to the cases that can applied this kind of while. I don't see other way to better the performance of for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you test `while` and `for` loops doing fundamentally the same thing, you'll find that the performance of them is nearly identical barring measurement error (and measurement error is **really easy to introduce**, what with CPUs that run at partial speed until/unless there's a lot of work to do, other processes running on the machine, etc., etc.).

Here's a more apples-to-apples comparison:

```
function loopWithWhileOneBillion() {
    var max = 1000000000;
    var start = Date.now();
    while (max--) {
    }
    var end = Date.now();
    return end - start;
}

function loopWithForOneBillion() {
    var max;
    var start = Date.now();
    for (max = 1000000000; max; max--) {
    }
    var end = Date.now();
    return end - start;
}
/* *************************************** */

/* loop with 10kkk interactions */
function loopWithWhileTenBillion() {
    var max = 10000000000;
    var start = Date.now();
    while (max--) {
    }
    var end = Date.now();
    return end - start;
}

function loopWithForTenBillion() {
    var max;
    var start = Date.now();
    for (max = 10000000000; max; max--) {
    }
    var end = Date.now();
    return end - start;
}
console.log("loopWithWhileOneBillion: " + loopWithWhileOneBillion());
console.log("loopWithForOneBillion: " + loopWithForOneBillion());
console.log("loopWithWhileTenBillion: " + loopWithWhileTenBillion());
console.log("loopWithForTenBillion: " + loopWithForTenBillion());
```

My results for three trials **after** a priming run to warm up the CPU:

```
trial  while1B for1B
----- -------- -----
1          988   987
2          983   981
3          983   989

trial while10B for10B
----- -------- ------
1        12248  12245
2        12243  12240
3        12245  12242
```

It don't get a lot closer than that...

Of course, this sort of benchmark is essentially useless; the loops have to be doing real work for there to be anything meaningful here. And of course, the real work of the loop will likely swamp any difference (if there were one) in the loop constructs.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for testing